# 'Java is not recognized...' error on Windows

Tags: java

I'm trying to give OrientDB a go on Windows, but I can't even seem to get it started. When I try to run the server.bat, I get the following error

```
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Basically, it's not seeing the %JAVA_HOME% variable, because when I did echo %JAVA_HOME% in the server.bat it didn't print anything.  The %JAVA_HOME% is set to this:

```
;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6
```

I also get the same error when I try:

```
java -version
```

Although if I open a command prompt and cd into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin' and type 'java -version' then it works just fine.  So I went into the server.bat, hardcoded the java path, but then I got the following error:

```
Error: no `server' JVM at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll'.
```

There is no such folder or jvm.dll.
I have set the PATH environment variable as well, although there seems to be a bunch of garbage in there (I added carriage returns for readability):

```
;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;
```

I'd really like to give this a try, but I can't seem to get past these issues.  I'm a C#/F# developer so I'm not well versed in the intricacies of Java.  Any helps would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nutshell: install a full JDK, use the `bin` directory of the JDK, not a JRE.

The JRE doesn't contain a server version of Java; the bin should point at a JDK `java` executable if you want to use the `-server` option. I'd recommend installing a JDK to a reasonable directory (avoid spaces) and use that one instead.